# Count the number of inclusive dates covered by a date period

Tags: c#, date, datetime

I'm looking to count the number of **dates** covered (inclusive) between two `DateTimes`.

This is not  `.TotalDays` as periods less than 24 hours may still return "2" by overlapping two different days. Likewise, two dates minutes apart should still return "1".

For example:

```
2012-2-1 14:00 to 2012-2-2 23:00 -> 2 (1st and 2nd Feb)
2012-2-1 14:00 to 2012-2-2 10:00 -> 2 (1st and 2nd Feb)
2012-2-1 23:00 to 2012-2-2 00:00 -> 2 (1st and 2nd Feb)
2012-2-1 23:00 to 2012-2-3 00:00 -> 3 (1st, 2nd, 3rd Feb)
2012-2-1 14:00 to 2012-2-1 15:00 -> 1 (1st Feb)
2012-2-1 14:00 to 2012-2-1 14:00 -> 1 (1st Feb)
2012-1-1 00:00 to 2012-12-31 23:59 -> 366 (All of 2012)
```

I can get this functionality with the code below:

```
DateTime dt1 = new DateTime(2000,1,2,12,00,00);
DateTime dt2 = new DateTime(2000,1,3,03,00,00);

int count = 0;
for (DateTime date = dt1; date.Date <= dt2.Date; date = date.AddDays(1))
    count++;

return count;
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: What about d1.Date.Subtract(d2.Date).TotalDays + 1

Comment: Not sure how it's a duplicate. Two dates on the same day should still return 1. A period less than 24 hours crossing two days should return two days.

Comment: NodaTime is great for this sort of thing, refer to:

[How to use NodaTime to calculate an inclusive days period][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10336863/how-to-use-nodatime-to-calculate-an-inclusive-days-period

Comment: This is not a duplicate as evidenced by the fact it has a different answer from the nominated duplicate...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Why not just:

```
int count = dt1.Date.Subtract(dt2.Date).Duration().Days + 1;
```

Using `.Date` normalizes the Date to midnight (0:00), add 1 to the `Days` to get the number of different dates, not just the number of days in between.

Using `Duration` makes sure you always get a positive answer.

Comment: That'll do it. Will accept when I can. I didn't notice that it was always off by 1 for all tests so good spot.

Comment: You can use a minus rather than `.Subtract` to simplify it a bit (as per @Tim Schmelter's answer)

Comment: @MattMitchell Yes, it's a question of preference, I like using Subtract when I'm chaining like this.

Comment: Incidentally, your `Duration()` should be a method call not a property. It actually handles misordered dates which my original sample doesn't.

Answer (score 9):

Perhaps simply

```
TimeSpan duration = dt2.Date - dt1.Date;
int days = duration.Days + 1;
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/JoUD1U)

Comment: Yep this does it, +1. Davio beat you to the punch unfortunately for accepted.

Comment: @MattMitchell: But i would use `TimeSpan.Days` anyway instead of `TotalDays` since you don't want to count fractions of days(`double`) but just the days component(`int`).

Comment: @MattMitchell: I see that Davio has also changed it so my argument is pointless anyway ;)

Comment: Yeah. If it was a breaking point I would have changed the accepted answer but it functionally didn't matter. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime d1=DateTime.MinValue;
DateTime d2=DateTime.MaxValue;
TimeSpan span=d2-d1;
int counter = span.Days + 1;
```

Comment: means u also wants to calculate months also

Answer (score 0):

Math.Ceiling((d2 - d1.Date).TotalDays)

Tried all cases you mentioned. And results are expected! Hope it helps.

Comment: Good effort but it won't handle 2000/1/1 23:00 to 2000/1/2 00:00 (it returns 1 and should be 2 as there are 2 dates there). See @Davio's accepted answer for a working solution.

Comment: @MattMitchell This demonstrates that mathematically "taking `Ceiling`" is not the same as "taking `Floor` and adding `1`". The latter would give a correct behavior.